# Test keypress in material-ui textfield with enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, enzyme

I'm using material-ui [TextField](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/) component like this:

```
<TextField
     name='currentValue'
     id='current-value'
     value={this.state.value}
     validate={this.validate}
     onChange={this.handleValueChange}
     InputProps={{ onKeyPress: this.handleKeyPress }}
/>
```

and I want to test `keypress` event but it's not working because material-ui TextField component doesn't have `onKeyPress` prop. it passes it to parent component so the event doesn't occur on the component. How could I test it? Here is my current test.

```
const wrapper = shallow(
    <MyTextField />
  ).first().shallow()
  wrapper.find('#current-value')
         .simulate('change', { target: { value: 'test2' }  })
  wrapper.find('#current-value')
         .simulate('keypress', { key: 'Enter' })
```